# Flutter Desktop Google based login(Authentication) using firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, desktop

I need add Google based login to my flutter desktop application using firebase or Google console.

I am seeing lot of blogs on Android,IOS   firebase authentication, not able to find any saple for desktop Google authentication using firebase or Google console.

Flutter desktop app Google authentication using firebase